# Shell Command in VBA Execution

Tags: vba, shell, cmd

I'm trying to run two lines of commands using shell. I haven't been able to find a good source on how to actually execute shell in VBA. So far, I have been able to figure out how to open a specific directory.

```
Sub shellCMD()
     Shell ("cmd.exe /k CD\Users\n808037\Desktop\OTHER")
End Sub
```

This will at least lead me to the directory where I need to go. However, now that I've gotten to the directory I need to go, I need to execute a command after. That is

**copy *.csv merged.csv**

How do I do this in shell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each `Shell` call runs in its own process, so you can't run separate commands by calling `Shell` consecutively. Generally, you'd want to either run multiple commands as a batch file or script if you were going to do a lot of processing.  In this case, just specify the full path for `copy`.  There's no need to change the working directory at all:

```
Shell "cmd.exe /k copy C:\Users\n808037\Desktop\OTHER\*.csv C:\Users\n808037\Desktop\OTHER\merged.csv"
```

Comment: Worked. Thank you!