# Why shell command generates runtime error 53?

Tags: vba, shell

I have a sub that has to merge all txt files into one named all.txt. It should be run by pressing a button associated to this sub, but it generates the Run-time error 53 File not found. The code is this:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Call Shell("copy c:\test\*.txt c:\test\all.txt", vbNormalFocus)
End Sub
```

Where is the error?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39756875/shell-command-in-vba-execution   and also worth reviewing: https://www.myonlinetraininghub.com/vba-shell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
copy
```

Is an internal command of CMD.exe

So

```
CMD /C copy blah blah
```

See

```
CMD /?
```

Comment: Please add a little more explaination. :)

Comment: it works now. Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Call Shell("cmd /c copy c:\test\*.txt c:\test\all.txt", vbNormalFocus)
End Sub